# Equality in the Bishop Gromov theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

How to work out the equality condition in the Bishop-Gromov theorem? i.e. when does the ratio of volumes not strictly decrease?

Reference :

http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/16S-RiemGeom/Notes/Lec24.pdf

Look at the remark at the end of the proof.

Comment: You **must** give some context + a web reference: very few readers are aware of the existence of this theorem, not to speak of the case of equality in it...

Comment: Please give some context to your question (for example, by quoting specific parts of the pdf relevant to the equality and then by stating it explicitly).